# When did Voyager-1 achieve Solar System escape velocity?

Tags: escape-velocity

Wikipedia's page on [escape velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity) puts the escape velocity for an object travelling out of the Solar System at ~525km/s. This figure is slightly higher than the [tentative velocity of Voyager-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyager_1) at ~17km/s.

Why is the vehicle spoken of as being on an interstellar course? When did the vehicle achieve Solar Escape velocity? What am I missing?

Comment: The answers are explaining the discrepancy, but I'm hoping someone can specifically summarize the path the probe has taken and its velocities at different points, since that info is pretty hard to acquire. E.g. could it have escaped the Sun after leaving Earth with no further boosts? Was it the Saturn slingshot that did the trick?

Comment: @Chris: The diagram in my answer says Voyager 2 exceeded solar escape velocity in its encounter with Jupiter, and then more with Saturn. I can't find a similar diagram for Voyager 1, but it must have been similar. According to the [*list of escape velocities*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity#List_of_escape_velocities), at Earth, it takes 11.2 km/s to escape Earth, but 42.1 km/s to escape the sun. That's like 14 times as much energy. That's how much harder it would be without the slingshot effect.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Escape velocity depends on what you're trying to escape from and how far away from it you are.
That Wikipedia reference makes that very clear.

As Sachin Shekhar pointed out, if you're in the vicinity of the sun, and you're trying to escape the galazy, you need 525 km/s.
If you're trying to escape the solar system, and you're at Neptune's distance from the sun, you only need 7.7 km/s.

When did Voyager 2 achieve escape velocity from the solar system? According to [this diagram from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyager_2#Launch_and_trajectory), it occurred during its gravity assist from Jupiter.
Voyager 1 was probably not too much different.

[image: Trajectory of Voyager 2]

Comment: Referenced [in a 2018-05-26 Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/link/Wild-new-theory-may-explain-why-some-aliens-never-leave-their-home-planet/response/Sami-Salmi) (or rather the comment to the question).

Answer (score 4):

525Km/s is escape velocity w.r.t. The Milky Way's gravity at the position of solar system galactic radius. You aren't trying to escape the galaxy. Are you?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is good news. It would be disappointing if they settled into a comet-like orbit, yet interesting to future humans who would see it return.

Just to confirm, this astronomy.com senior editor also says yes, they have both achieved solar escape velocity. I imagine moving gravity wells but can’t quite grasp how the slingshot effect works.
[https://astronomy.com/magazine/ask-astro/2019/01/no-returns#:~:text=Take%20Voyager%201%20as%20an,(79%2C000%20km%2Fh)](https://astronomy.com/magazine/ask-astro/2019/01/no-returns#:%7E:text=Take%20Voyager%201%20as%20an,(79%2C000%20km%2Fh)).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/402063)